# Windows 7: Save open windows

Tags: windows-7

I'm looking for some piece of software that will save an open window configuration to a keyboard shortcut.

For instance, I have Chrome on 1 screen, Eclipse on another. I want to save that to a keyboard shortcut (say CTRL + ALT + F1) then if I switch to Outlook on 1 screen and Photoshop on another, I can save that as another shortcut (CTRL + ALT + F2). Then when I want to switch between the 2 views, I just hit the keyboard shortcut and it automatically brings the proper windows to the front of my screen.

Is there anything like that out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [WinSize2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winsize2/).

> WinSize: Move windows automatically to a predefined place. Resize width and/or height. Moving OR changing size possible. Supports text CONTAINED in titles (like "Notepad") to identify window. One hotkey for all fcts